# Latitude E6540 Windows 10 brightness not available

Tags: windows-10, dell-latitude

The brightness controls on my laptop wont work after an upgrade to Windows 10.

In addition, the brightness slider in the Power Options control panel is also missing.

I have ran and installed the drivers from Dell, using the Dell Detect app, but still nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in CMD to check if there any power option controls there or not?

```
powercfg /l
```

Example:
[image]

If it shows up then you can enable it via a registry edit.

Comment: I got the exact same screen when I ran `powercfg /l`